# AJAX Post Request with Raw HTTP Request - Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am looking for a way to send the following POST request using only plain Javascript:

Let's say the above HTTP request was a variable, would it maybe be possible to send that as a request and gather the result? Or is it a better way to send this POST request using Javascript?

Thanks in advance for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work as long as it is your own api that you are calling to?

```
var post = function() {
  var url = "http://www.example.com";
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      request.open( "POST", url, true);
      request.send(null);   
}
```

Comment: But what about the other data in the header, like the secret key and the date, which is required. This is not my own API.